# With Pandas Calculate Diff , but with different columns

Tags: python, pandas

Give Data As

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": [1, 4, 8, 12], "Stop": [2, 6, 9, 13]})
# Calculate df['lag'] = Previous[Stop] - This[Start]
```

Lag = NA for first Row.
Else Lag = Current Row Start  - Previous Row Stop

Output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": [1, 4, 8, 12], "Stop": [2, 6, 9, 13],"lag":[np.nan,2,2,3]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `shift`

```
df['lag'] = df['Start'] - df['Stop'].shift()

   Start  Stop  lag
0      1     2  NaN
1      4     6  2.0
2      8     9  2.0
3     12    13  3.0
```